# Arch Sound output only showing as Headphone while no headphone plugged

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I've struggled couple of days to fix this issue with installing / uninstalling / editing alsa , pulseaudio setting but no luck . 
One time i was able to fix audio with alsamixer and select output devices from f6 key. but after restart it's gone and afterward alsamixer select no working.
here is my

```
bash alsa-info.sh --upload
```

output .

[ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=2856ad7c4eebf6f1add3658b59eda1340b51f76c)

I'm running ApricityOS latest version atm .
please let me know if you need more information about it.

Comment: Have you had any luck with `pavucontrol`? When i have seen problems with the wrong in/output being selected I've had good luck fixing it there.

Comment: Yes still can not fixed .